# Instantly synchronizing two tables in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin UI, I have the following scenario:

[image: Table sketch]

In other words, there are two tables:

- a "master" table that is editable,
- a "slave" table that is non-editable, but must contain the same data as the master table, however with a potentially different sort order.

The final requirement precludes the tables having the same `Container` (in my understanding, which might be wrong).

What I've done currently is that I attach an `ItemSetChangeListener` and a `ValueChangeListener`, and use the events to update the data accordingly.

Here's the current crude implementation (in Scala actually, but I hope it's readable enough, if not, please comment) :

```
class DataTableSynchronizer(val master: Table, val slave: Table) extends ItemSetChangeListener with ValueChangeListener {

  def init():Unit = {
    master.addItemSetChangeListener(this)
    containerMaster.addListener(this.asInstanceOf[ValueChangeListener])

  }

  private def containerOf(t: Table) = t.getContainerDataSource().asInstanceOf[IndexedContainer]

  private def containerMaster = containerOf(master)

  private def containerSlave = containerOf(slave)

  override def containerItemSetChange(event: ItemSetChangeEvent) {
    //handling 
    //remove all items that have been deleted
    for(toDel <- containerSlave.getItemIds().filterNot(containerMaster.containsId(_))) {
      containerSlave.removeItem(toDel)
    }

    //add new items to the start
    for(toAdd <- containerMaster.getItemIds().filterNot(containerSlave.containsId(_))) {
      containerSlave.addItem(toAdd)
    }
    slave.validate();
  }

  override def valueChange(event: ValueChangeEvent) = {
      updateValuesInResults()
  }

  private def updateValuesInResults(): Unit = {
    //update all values in the "slave" table from the "master" table
    for((itemData,itemResults) <- containerMaster.getItemIds().map(id => (containerMaster.getItem(id),containerSlave.getItem(id)))) {
      for(propId <- itemData.getItemPropertyIds()) {
        itemResults.getItemProperty(propId).asInstanceOf[Property[Any]].setValue(itemData.getItemProperty(propId).getValue().asInstanceOf[Any])
      }
    }
  }

}
```

However, my problem is that **I need the data to be synchronized continuously, as the user types**, which is not happening due to the relevant events being sent only after some operation completes (a row is added, etc.).

How do I solve this, i.e. **how do I enforce events being emitted often enough to enable continuous synchronization?** The only idea I had was to use an `ActionListener` mapping all the keys, but that screams "abuse".

*Note:* I realize doing this through the server-side is less efficient, but this is not a concern in my case. However, client-side-based answers are OK as well, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the TextChangeEventMode of the editor to EAGER and process single keystrokes in the event listener:

```
    TextField textField = ...;
    textField.setTextChangeEventMode(TextChangeEventMode.EAGER);
    textField.addTextChangeListener(new TextChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void textChange(TextChangeEvent event) {
            String text = event.getText();
            // sync with other component
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Don't have access to the app code now, I'll verify & accept as soon as I can. BTW, do I understand correctly that I'll have to provide a custom ` TableFieldFactory` for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you have to do that to supply your own implementation of a text field.